# Authorize Application on Facebook after authorization redirect to my page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, authorization

Its a possible to make Facebook application, which after search on Facebook send my authdialog and after this dialog when I accepted it application redirect me to my website with whole information like.

id, access_token and other which i request in authdialog.

Steps

1. Facebook Search (name of application)
2. After click to application redirect to authdialog on Facebook.
3. After accept redirect to my website outside of Facebook (landing page)

Thank for your advice.

Comment: So, after they authorize your application, you want to redirect to another website that explains your application?

Answer (score 0):

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

The `redirect_uri` param is what you're after.